# Is my bathroom wet-venting plan reasonable?

Tags: plumbing

I‘m relocating my bathroom fixtures and laid out my plumbing using a wet vent. I would likefeed back about whether this is a good plan. Do I need another vent for the shower or suggestions on different layout?

See drawing. The cleanout is the existing drain.
Added different layout with toilet going perpendicular to drain,

Hi All,
I relayed the plumbing but have to move my drain out to make room to fit the fittings.  I jog the drain with (2) 22.5 elbows, is this allowed 22.5 to use in horizontal? See Dwg-3, Thanks[image]

[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpsVb.jpg): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVl63.jpg)[image]

Comment: What plumbing code is adopted in your Local Area Having Jurisdiction (LAHJ)? The various codes are aligned in intent but different in details. I don't see anything screamingly wrong under the "Mostly IPC with local changes" I have to deal with. But there are **many, many options** of ways to vent things in the IPC, so winkling out which bit applies can be tricky sometimes. And the UPC or other code can differ on various points.

Comment: Hi, I’m in Southern California and I think is the UPC, so I’m good with one wet vent? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Under IPC you have "a bathroom group" which is specifically blessed, and also your vertical wet vent is 2" and only carrying 1 DFU (of drainage - venting 6, or 5 if the toilet is low-enough flow), while the horizontal wet vet is 3" and only carrying 6 DFUs, both of which are well within the IPC limits. Someone with a better handle on UPC will be along in a while, I'm reasonably sure.

Comment: if it's convenient I'd go with shallower bends in the 3" cleanout, (like 15 degrees or less) if anyone has to use the cleanout  the straighter it is the better.

Comment: One of the most detailed plumbing previews I have seen.   This would pass in my area for sure - 2" venting plenty for standard bathroom.   Jasen makes a good point too.   I have seen sharp bends in cleanouts be a PITA to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

All of these layouts look good. The venting should be fine. You're connecting the lines with wyes, not tees, which is good. 45° Bends in the 3" cleanout line should be fine; a snake will easily make the turn.

Altogether, it looks like you've put a lot of thought into this. My one recommendation would be to check your state venting code to see the maximum distance allowed between a drain and its vent, just to make sure everything is close enough. I don't foresee a problem, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the pipe but I’ll check. Thanks